# How I can hide or remove (from ~) tags when I copy/paste Diagram Elements in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

[image]

In Enterprise Architect, when I copy and paste elements from A diagram to B diagram,
*(from A diagram)* <- I want to remove(or hide) this tag which is placed below elements.
How I can do this?

I tried to find this option in menu Start > Preferences but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control that setting through the diagram properties: **Diagram | Appearance | Show Namespace**

[image]